# How to dynamically filter DataTable in ASP.NET based on SQL Query input from user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datatable

Is there any way to possibly filter data in DataTable without using LINQ and Entity Framework? Output can be Enumerable.

I was able to run 2nd line of code using LINQ and Basic filter using **myDataTable.Select** statement.

`myDataTable.Select("[Name] is NULL OR [Name] <> 'n/a'" )`

`myDataTable.Select("select sum(col1), col2 group by col1, col2")`

Comment: Your two lines of code don't use LINQ but [`DataTable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=net-5.0

Answer (score -1):

DataTable is spesific object and you produce a datatable any ways. For examle with code or with SqlConnection object. What is your database name?

For filter to datatable, i use this code in my project:

```
dim dt as DataTable
Dim result() As DataRow = dt.Select("ColumnName='" & YourValue & "')
```

Comment: Please read the question: "without using LINQ".

Comment: Do you want use For Each loop? Example: For Each row As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows
                if isDBNull(row("Name")) then  your codes....
            Next